# Word 2007 document shrinks upon printing

Tags: printing

My printer has the latest driver and works great with other programs (Illustrator, InDesign, AutoCAD) and even works great with Word 2007--except for one document. Originally this document is a size 7 x 10 (and it printed fine), but I changed that to 5 x 7 with half inch margins all around. Now it prints a mini-page of about 2 x 3. It is a perfect print, but just chipmunk sized. Increasing the margins to three-quarters all around does not help. Resizing it to original size or even 8.5 x 11 allows it to print normal, but I need the smaller 5 x 7 size. As a final note, all of the above mentioned printing is done on 8.5 x 11 paper. I am using Word and a desktop printer with letter size paper for draft purposes, but the final product will be a 5 x 7 booklet.

Comment: " I changed that to 5 x 7 " - do you mean you've changed paper size?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear: the printed paper is always 8.5 x 11 (both printer settings and actual paper), but I change the document size and margins in Word settings.

Comment: What is document site? How exactly did you set it?

Comment: My document size of 5" x 7" with half inch margins and portrait orientation is set with the MSWord Page Layout tab--you know, like is normally done.  The document scales down to about 2" x 3" when printing on letter size paper, but Scaling options are not enabled (neither in Word Options > Display, nor in Printing Options > Advanced).  The document always Previews perfectly.  I hope you have some good ideas because I have run out...

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your document to a PDF and print that. Some printers and other services have a hard time displaying (or for that matter, printing) margins changes and such.

Comment: Yeah, I did that (.pdf) and it printed fine; but that felt like fixing my hypothetical car (that will not steer to the left) by driving a huge clockwise circle around the city to get to my left-side destination, yes?  But, sincerely thanks for your suggestion and as I said--that idea does work.

Comment: I think that's quite an exaggeration; I always print my documents with PDF, since that way I can be sure the formatting won't be twisted. Exporting through MS Word takes like, what 20 seconds? Won't call that a ride around town.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain better...our proofing of illustrations and AutoCAD diagrams are going page by page for changes to lineweights and their scaling to the page.  So, it is a procedure of repetitive printing of one page over and over, between revisions, then on to the next page.  It would be nice to just use Word's Quick Print feature, which we were able to do until the recent glitch occurred.  Since then we have been forced to "drive around town", as that does seem to be the only option, just as you pointed out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer to the problem, but not to the glitch source.  The trick is in printer page setup (not Word page setup).  Seems my Word document tells my printer to ignore its size setting.  Even though the printer setting is for "letter", I select an arbitrary other size, then re-select "letter."  Now my 5 x 7 document prints actual 5 x 7 on a 8.5 x 11 paper.  This procedure has to be done only on the first printing of the document: thereafter the setting holds.  Note that I only have a few Word documents with this problem, and they all are of size 5 x 7.  Thanks for all of the concerned help.

Answer (score 0):

If a particular word doc starts printing at 50% of intended, and other docs print ok- MS word is corrupted.  I worked for days on this problem troubleshooting, etc. Solution; I was going to reinstall MS Office Pro from my saved download file and when I opened the file it showed several options, one was "repair".  this solved the problem of "phantom" downsizing when printing.
Other option is to reinstall MS Office.  Hope this helps.